# Очередность выполнения get запросов с использованием afnetworking

Tags: ios, rest, afnetworking

Коллеги, доброе время суток!

Пишу приложение которое работает с несколькими сервисами отдающими данные в JSON. В качестве библиотеки работы с сетью использую AFNetworking. Приложение должно с определенной последовательностью отправлять запросы на сервисы в определенном порядке который зависит от результатов полученных в ответах.

Вопрос в том как лучше реализовать очередность выполнения запросов с сервисам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас нет времени на детальный ответ, но вам стоит копнуть в сторону `operationQueue`

Дока по AFN лежит здесь: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/index.html

Comment: http://samwize.com/2013/03/02/queue-http-operations-with-afnetworking/ - это оно?

Comment: @huffman, похоже на то.